# Using in background thread Google Play billing library v3

Tags: java, android, android-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

I'm migrating my code from old AIDL google play billing system to the newer Google Play Billing library v3. I used old code in background threads to check if a purchase was present for example. The new library uses several listeners and methods like `newBuilder`, `startConnection` and `endConnection` are marked as `UIThread`. At this point it seems quite hard to create a `BillingClient` in a background thread just to call `queryPurchase`. The constructor of `BillingClient` is actually public, but docs says you cannot call any method until the connection is performed using `startConnection`. I didn't find any example to query something in background, any tips?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm moving from AIDL to 4.0 and I have issues with my sync server calls in background thread because someone in Google decided to mess old good working things up.